# set bottom divider/separator of expandable listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, expandablelistview

I'm trying to include a bottom/footer divider for my expandable listview but to now avail. Currently I have a expandable listview which appears as in the [linked image](http://tinypic.com/r/5zffaa/6).

I've set android:footerDividersEnabled="true" in the xml file which defines the expandable listview but no dice.

I've also defined a view which is 1dp high to act as a bottom divider but again no luck.

Something simple I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the footer divider to appear I think you need to add a footer view (even empty):

```
    listView.setFooterDividersEnabled(true);
    listView.addFooterView(new View(listView.getContext()));
```

Comment: Perhaps it's different for type ExpandableListView? I notice your solution mentions listView. Just guessing here...

Comment: BAH! It does work! I was looking at the wrong ExpandableListView... Cheers Fiddler!